# How can I crop a raster (within a function) that is used by catalog_apply() in lidR, using Terra instead of Raster?

Tags: lidr, terra

I have older code to crop a chunk within a function (to avoid edge effects when later merging CHM tiles together (i.e., edge pixels derived without enough data. The extend of 1 is to avoid little gaps)), similar to the idea in example 1 here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/2.2.1/topics/catalog_apply

Raster works but I would like to use Terra instead. I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot get an Extent object from argument y
```

I could try to convert the `SpatExtent` to an `Extent`, but it would be clunky. Maybe there's an easy way?

Below is part of my code (the Raster lines which work are commented out):

```
library(raster)
library(terra)

chunk <- ??? 
chm <- ??? 

bbox <- terra::ext(chunk)
bbox <- terra::extend(bbox, 1)
chm  <- terra::crop(chm, bbox)

#bbox <- raster::extent(chunk)
#bbox <- raster::extend(bbox, 1)
#chm  <- raster::crop(chm, bbox)
```

edits:  minimal example, but with lidR code...

```
library(terra)
library(lidR)

ctgNorm <- readLAScatalog(system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR"))

ctgNorm@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE

makeCHM_function = function(chunk) {
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las))
    return(NULL)
  chm <- grid_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(4, 2.5), subcircle = 0.3))
  rast(chm)
  # Wrong way to get extent... bbox <- terra::ext(chunk)
  # correct way:
  bbox <- lidR::extent(chunk)
  bbox <- terra::extend(bbox, 1)
  chm  <- terra::crop(chm, bbox)
  return(chm)
}

opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 25
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/processingTest20230509a/chm/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"
myCHM <- catalog_apply(ctgNorm, makeCHM_function)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible, example* that shows the output (error message) where it occurs? That is, add some example data generated by code. I have remove code that you do not need, and added some that you do.

Comment: thanks Robert. I had trouble with the sample laz file. I put lidR specific code in if that helps.

Comment: In your lidR example, it looks like you are using "raster" code (the use of `terra::` is meaningless as explained in my answer).  `bbox <- terra::ext(chunk)` is the way to go if you want to use terra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can simply be written

```r
library(terra)
library(lidR)

ctgNorm <- readLAScatalog(system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR"))

ctgNorm@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE
opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 25
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/processingTest20230509a/chm/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"
chm = rasterize_canopy(ctgNorm, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(4, 2.5), subcircle = 0.3))
```

Comment: Thanks JRR that's certainly better and I'll use that instead of my code. In the case of the tree_detection and rumple_index_surface examples from the link above, would lidR::extent() replace raster::extent()? Or is this better answered in a new question? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/2.2.1/topics/catalog_apply

Comment: Ask a new question. You are using old functions deprecated so the best is to start on a new clean basis.

Comment: There is no such thing as `lidR::extent` because `extent` is a generic function. lidR implements the method for LAS* objects. raster implements it for Raster* objects. These are complimentary implementations of the same method (name) for different objects. One does not replace the other.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that chunk and chm are RasterLayer or other Raster* objects.

```
library(raster)
chm   <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3, ext=extent(0,2,0,2))
chunk <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3, ext=extent(0,1,0,1))
```

Now you do

```
library(terra)
bbox <- ext(chunk)
bbox <- extend(bbox, 1)
chm  <- crop(chm, bbox)
# Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y
```

This happens because "bbox" is a "SpatExtent" and "chm" is a "RasterLayer". The  `crop` method for RasterLayer (implemented in the "raster" package) does not know about SpatExtent, it needs an Extent. To use a SpatExtent, you need to use the method for SpatRaster, implemented in the "terra" package:

```
chm <- rast(chm)
chm  <- crop(chm, bbox)
```

It seems that you (with many others) believe that there is a difference between a call to `terra::crop(x, y)` and to `raster::crop(x, y)`. That is not the case. `crop` is a generic function, the implementation you get depends on the class of `x`, not on the `namespace::`.

Here is an illustration. Below I use the `ncol` method implemented in "raster" for a RasterLayer --- using `base::` does not change anything.

```
base::ncol(chunk)
#[1] 3
```

This situation can be different when using standard (non-generic) functions with the same name from different packages, especially when there are name conflicts (including from generics defined independently in different packages).

Bottom line: if you want to use terra methods, and you get Raster* objects from another package, you should start by coercing these to a SpatRaster.

Comment: I think I see that now. bbox isn't a raster. I have to look at this a bit to see why Raster was able to get the extent of bbox...

Comment: Okay, I messed that up. Although bbox <- raster::extent(chunk) works, it really should be bbox <- lidR::extent(chunk). I didn't realize lidR had the extent() function too. Sorry about that. I did edit the code above so it works with Terra and Raster isn't needed. Thanks.

Comment: That is not correct.  `lidR::extent` returns an Extent; it is the same as raster::extent (see my answer...). If you do that you are using "raster" methods, not "terra" methods.

Comment: My question should have been worded better in hindsight. I wanted to run the lidR catalog_apply() without the Raster package in the function. In the old lidR 2.2.1 example, raster::extent() is used. I don't know why lidR::extent() works but I can now just rely on lidR for extent and Terra for extend and crop.

Comment: You are mistaken. You are writing terra::crop but that does not use terra, that uses raster in your case. Again, the method you use does not depend on the "terra::" or "raster::" bit, it is determined by the class of the first argument. In this case that is not a SpatRaster, so you are not using terra (I illustrated that with ncol). I have shown how you can use "terra", that is, by using rast(chm). Perhaps read my answer again?

Comment: I just read it again and now I see that my lack of understanding of namespace and dependencies was the root of my confusion. You answered a question I didn't know I had, thanks.